# Placing 2d on a grid in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tiles-game, ngui

I built a small MapEditor for my game in XNA. Now I want to build it in Unity3d, except I don't really understand how this works in Unity3d.

So basically what I want is to create a 2d grid, where I can dynamically add tiles to the grid. Each tile contains a 2d Texture.

I was thinking of using NGUI to help me with this. I want it to be a 2d game.

I've got no idea on how this works in Unity3d. I would appreciate it, if you guys could point me into the correct direction.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Rotorz tile system is doing exactly what you are looking for. Have a look at: http://u3d.as/content/rotorz-limited/rotorz-tile-system/2UU